# Display corrected video stream in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I have to display a video stream from an ethernet camera into a WinForm C# 4.0 application. I made some tests with the software of the camera and I saw that the image provided by the camera was distorted by lenses. 
I know that it's possible to correct the image using a calibration grid. 
Do you have any feedback about some image processing libraray that can  be use for this purpose? The library not necessary need to be free.
For some other projects I use Halcon or OpenCV, but I don't know witch one is the best for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV can do it without any problem. There are a lot of implementations of camera calibration with OpenCV:

- [Here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php?title=Camera_Calibration) you have the official version of EmguCV calibration, it uses the [`CameraCalibration`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.4.0.0/html/7519b512-7a6a-f7f5-859d-d65e3e7fa58e.htm) class
- Or you can find the official OpenCV's sample application of camera calibration on [OpenCV's GitHub](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/calibration.cpp), but this one is a native implementation.